# Using bit manipulation to calculate the mean value of two number?

Tags: bit-manipulation

I find this code :

```
int mid = (l & r) + ((l ^ r) >> 1)
```

which is the same as `mid=(l+r)/2`

but i can't figure why?

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Take two numbers, write down the binary equivalents of those numbers, and perform the operations on paper. That should help you understand what's going on.

Comment: it doesn't work for *negative* numbers, e.g. `l = 4; r = -5` expected result is `-1` while actual one is `0`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not quite the same, the point of it is not being the same. It is *mostly* the same, but without overflow trouble: if you input two positive numbers, the result will never be negative. That is not true of `mid = (l + r) / 2`, if you have for example `l = 0x7fffffff, r = 1` then the true midpoint is `0x40000000` but the naive midpoint calculation says it is `0xc0000000`, a large negative number.

Addition can be decomposed into:

```
x + y = (x ^ y) + ((x & y) << 1)
```

That's just a simple "calculate per-digit sum, then apply the carries separately" decomposition. Then shift the whole thing right by 1 while restoring the bits that "fell off the end" by just not shifting left to begin with and shifting the other thing to the right,

```
x + y = ((x ^ y) >> 1) + (x & y)
```

Which is that midpoint calculation. Note that it rounds *down*, not towards zero, which matters for negative results. I would not call the result *wrong*, it's still halfway in between the endpoints, but it does not match the result from a normal signed division by 2 (usually rounds towards zero, though opinions about how it should round differ).

You can change it to work for all *unsigned* integers by using an unsigned right shift:

```
// unsigned midpoint without wrapping/overflow
int mid = (l & r) + ((l ^ r) >>> 1);
```

Of course being the unsigned midpoint, negative inputs are implicitly treated as very large positive numbers, that's the point.

If you're working with signed-but-non-negative numbers (as is usually the case for midpoint calculation), you can use the significantly simpler

```
int mid = (x + y) >>> 1
```