# Why use bitwise operator to calculate average?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, guava

Wondering why does Guava use bitwise to calculate avg between 2 values ([mean](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/math/IntMath.java))?
I've run the benchmark on the 2 methods and they seem very similar in performance.

```java
// non-bitwise
int avg = x + (y - x) / 2;
```

```java
// bitwise
int avg = (x & y) + ((x ^ y) >> 1);
```

Comment: Which `meanRoundDown` are you asking about?  Please provide a link to the javadoc or source code.

Comment: duplicates: [Using bit manipulation to calculate the mean value of two number?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44109340/995714), [Explanation of the safe average of two numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19106350/995714)

Comment: Try `x = Integer.MAX_VALUE` and `y = Integer.MIN_VALUE`, and you'll see why the non bitwise has problems. The problem with add and subtract is that you can overflow or underflow. So, use something that is safe.

Comment: Whoever downvoted, I really find no reason to do.